# Logback: Double-nested Field via <nestedField>

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I have a Java web service running on Spring Boot 2 and JDK 11 that uses Logback via a template file in a common library. I am using the `<nestedField>` tag to place some default Logback properties at locations conformant to Elastic Common Schema, and additionally locations specified by my organization's standards. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful at nesting a property at more than one level in the resulting JSON. Allow me to illustrate.

The template file in the common library looks something like this:

```xml
    <included>
        <appender name="MACHINE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <providers>
                    <timestamp/>
                    <nestedField>
                        <fieldName>log</fieldName>
                        <providers>
                            <loggerName>
                                <fieldName>logger</fieldName>
                            </loggerName>
                            <logLevel>
                                <fieldName>level</fieldName>
                            </logLevel>
                        </providers>
                    </nestedField>

                    <message/>

                    <pattern>
                        <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                        <pattern>
                            <!--@formatter:off-->
                            {
                                "lots-of-other-MDC-fields-here": {...}
                            }
                            <!--@formatter:on-->
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>

                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </included>
```

The resulting JSON looks something like:

```
    {
      "log": {
        "logger": "...",
        "level: "INFO"
      },
      "message": "...",
      "lots-of-other-MDC-fields-here": {...}
    }
```

However, not all fields are only nested one level. In the outermost `<providers>` tag above I want to add in the following:

```xml
    <nestedField>
        <fieldName>extra</fieldName>
        <providers>
            <nestedField>
            <fieldName>keywords</fieldName>
                <stackHash>
                    <fieldName>stack_hash</fieldName>
                    <exclusions>${STE_EXCLUSIONS}</exclusions>
                </stackHash>
            </nestedField>
        </providers>
    </nestedField>
```

This should render like:

```
    {
      "log": {
        "logger": "...",
        "level: "INFO"
      },
      "extra": {
        "keywords": {
          "stack_hash": "something here"
        }
      },
      "message": "...",
      "lots-of-other-MDC-fields-here": {...}
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm not doing something right when I nest `<nestedField>` under another `<nestedField>` and I've failed to find any applicable documentation or examples on how this is done properly. I am looking for clear examples on how to get the configuration presented in my examples to render as the above output.

The actual output of the above example is:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@67:40 - no applicable action for [stackHash], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][providers][nestedField][providers][nestedField][stackHash]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@69:45 - no applicable action for [exclusions], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][providers][nestedField][providers][nestedField][stackHash][exclusions]]
```

For context, here is how my service is using the deployed template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProfile name="deployed-mode">
        <include resource="com/.../logging/logback/my-logback-template.xml"/>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="MACHINE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the format above is valid, there must have been a bug in the logstash encoder. I have been unable to pinpoint where that bug was as it resolved on its own. Currently using logstash encoder 6.2. If anyone knows more precisely what fixes this bug I will accept that answer instead.